# ShaderGraph Material Color change

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

I made a ShaderGraph Shader, that I applied to a material. In the SHader, I put in "public" a variable Color in order to change the material color. From the inspector, it do work if it is not runtime ;

I would like to change this material color depending on different elements during the game. The Material is applied to a lineRenderer. I tried many ways, but it never change color ;
[image]

```
GetComponent<EnemyType>().color; return a RGBA color. I tried :

     LaserLine.material.color = GetComponent<EnemyType>().color;
     LaserLine.startColor = GetComponent<EnemyType>().color;
     LaserLine.endColor = GetComponent<EnemyType>().color;
     LaserLine.material.SetColor("_Color", GetComponent<EnemyType>().color);
```

What Am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found out,

It is not the name of the property that count but the reference. To see it, go inside ShaderGraph, and click on the property, you will find the reference name on the property parameters (top left) :

[image]

Change the parameter value using the reference trough code like this

```
    material.SetColor("_Color", new Color());
```

Answer (score 4):

## As you are using a custom shader, properties might have different names

Based on the [screenshot in your other question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJMns.png) your color property is named "Color" not "_Color", though it's hard to see (because for some reason you scaled the images for that question) and I don't know what kind of code ShaderGraph actually outputs (e.g. it could just be a color node and its actual internal name is something like "_Node-2389").

If you hit this button and then "edit shader" it'll show you some information about the shader's properties, including the true string representation of each one.

[image: Shader settings]

Like this:

[image: Shader properties]